# cli interface with value type as return and C# interface implementation

Tags: c#, interface, c++-cli, value-type

I have 
1. CLI library with declared interface(*InterfaceCLI*) and implemented value type(*PointD*)
2. C# library with class(*PointD*) that implements interface from 1

The problem is strange interface implementation on C#. It requires such code
        public ValueType GetPoint()
intstead of
        public PointD GetPoint()

Sample code CLI:

```
public value struct PointD
//public ref class PointD
{
public:
    PointD(double x, double y);
    // Some stuff
};

public interface class InterfaceCLI
{
public:
    double Foo();
    PointD^ GetPoint();
};
```

Sample code C#:

```
public class Class1 : InterfaceCLI
{
    public double Foo()
    {
        PointD x=new PointD( 1.0 , 2.7 );
        return x.Y;
    }

    public ValueType GetPoint()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    /*
    public PointD GetPoint()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
     */
}
```

Why does it want ValueType  instead of PointD  in the class Class1?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PointD^ GetPoint();
```

Value types are not reference types.  So you should *not* use the ^ hat here.  Unfortunately this syntax is permitted in C++/CLI, it becomes a boxed value.  Very wasteful.  There's no direct equivalent for that in C#, beyond emulating it with ValueType as you found out.

Remove the hat to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is solved. It seems to me I have to use PointD% for value types. Why I shouldnot use PointD% in this case?

Comment: That means something completely different, used to pass function arguments by reference.  Any C++/CLI introductory book will tell you about this.